# How to add a string at the end of url

Tags: php, curl

I use cURL to send requests to REST API and I would like to add a string to created url befeore execute it. This string is not a parameter.

Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Show us some code and explain with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on really what you want to do. If you want to call an URL by appending GET query parameters, you can use [string concatenation](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html).

```
<?php
function get_data($url, $add) {
    $url = $url.$add;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo get_data('http://example.com', '?page=mine');
?>
```

However, if you want to retrieve a specific URL by sending POST query parameters (e.g. to simulate a form being submitted), you need to implement [something like this](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) instead.

Comment: ok, but what if I want to add $add variable after execute         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->params); method ?

Comment: @Mirek `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` doesn't modify the URL in any way.

Comment: RIGHT...:/ sorry, for that question. So I have to add this appendix at the end of $url varaible from example above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's called [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). In php it can be done: `$str = $string1.$string2;`

p.s. Always read documentation before asking something. There you can find answers on most of your questions.

Comment: Hm, it's not about only php string concatenation. My question is about how can I get uri(with parameters added using curl), add at the end of this uri a string, and then execute it using curl.

Comment: @Mirek `$url = 'http://example.com/'; $params = '?param1=value1&param2=value2'; $url .= $params;`